# Execution of a test case in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, execution, testcase

Is there a way to jump from the test case onto the test execution?
I have created a test plan with a test suite, I would like to assign team members to run specific tests. For example, test plan A has got test case A attached with user A assigned.
How can user A pass or fail this test case A without going to the test plan to do so. At the moment, the team can only run the test from the test plans page. I would like to pass or fail this test from the test case itself and view the results, like we can using test plans.

I have tried to create a user item on the Kanban board and add a test, but I don't see a way to connect this test to the test plan.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to create a user item on the Kanban board and add a test,
> but I don't see a way to connect this test to the test plan. Any help
> would be appreciated!

Go Boards=>Boards=>Settings=>Cards=>Tests, you can select an existing Test Plan.

[image]

And if you add a test after that, you can easily execute it via `more` option:

[image]